# myisamchk: error: 140 when opening MyISAM-table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this error when run repair?

```
myisamchk: error: 140 when opening MyISAM-table '/var/lib/mysql/zibarsho_karno/wp_yoast_seo_links.MYI'
```

how i can fix this ???

Comment: Run without ".MYI" 

`myisamchk -a /var/lib/mysql/zibarsho_karno/wp_yoast_seo_links`

Ref: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87729#c467037

Comment: want to run this myisamchk --safe-recover /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI

Answer (score 12):

```
ls *.MYI | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | xargs myisamchk -F -U
```

Saved me here because of basename extra operand and other issue. Please note ***-F -U*** are for ***Fast*** and ***UPDATE STATUS*** flag. You can use without it.

Comment: upvoted because you can do this from the base directory, starting from ls * / *.MYI

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug already reported since MySQL 5.6

Still happening in 8.0.11 so in the mean time you can use the walkarround solution.

Not using the MYI extension.

```
myisamchk  --force --update-state var/lib/mysql/zibarsho_karno/wp_yoast_seo_links
```

Comment: And does still exist in 8.0.15 - reported 2017 as a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87729) and not fixed yet.

Answer (score 7):

As user [Jesus Uzcanga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5446162/jesus-uzcanga) already mentioned, it is an old [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87729) which hasn't been fixed yet [current version is 8.0.15].

These commands are a workaround when you run it directly in the directory where the `.MYI` files are located:

```
ls *.MYI | xargs basename -s .MYI | xargs myisamchk
```

It removes the extension and runs `myisamchk` for each MyISAM data file.

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know `xargs`. This seems to be a powerful command/program.

Comment: Adding -r to the myisamchk command here would also repair the damaged tables.

Answer (score 2):

try use this :

```
find /var/lib/mysql/*/* -name '*.MYI' | sed -e 's/\.MYI$//' | xargs -I{} myisamchk -r -f -o {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.MYI | xargs basename -s .MYI | xargs -I{} myisamchk -r --force {}
```

Comment: Please share some explanation for that code such that others can learn from it

Comment: ls lists files. xargs takes a list of files, and runs a command. basename -s is designed to specify a suffix to remove. xargs typically (e.g., when -L 1 is not used) puts as many list items on the command line was what will fit, so everything before the secnd pipe ends up making a second list.  That list gets fed to another xargs.  -I {} specifies that will be used as a filename, so that instead of placing a filename at the end of a command line, youc an place it where you want it.  (There isn't much point to using -I {} early on, and then ending with {}.)  Multiple tables will be myisamchk'ed